# How to add Bleed and Crop Marks to an image in Python

Tags: python, printing, python-imaging-library

Trying to programmatic-ally add bleed and crop marks to an image before printing. The issue is that I don't want to loose the 3mm at each side of the image, and for this reason, the manual procedure is used to be extending the sides of the image by mirroring them over a bleed line using InDesign, I wonder how to do something similar using Python.

Comment: remember, OpenCV is for *computer vision*, not for drawing. -- your copyMakeBorder solution doesn't add such marks. it merely adds padding to the image array. -- you should investigate **imagemagick** for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this using cv2.copyMakeBorder() from OpenCV librar method, as following:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("illustration1.jpg")

#Window name in which image is displayed
window_name = 'Image.jpg'

#Using cv2.copyMakeBorder() method
image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(borderoutput, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
cv2.BORDER_REFLECT_101, None, value = 0)

#Displaying the image
cv2.imwrite(window_name, image)
```